# NULL SOAP response in .NET C#

Tags: c#, soap, null

The result of one of my SOAP methodes is always NULL although data is sent by the server on the network.

I think it is because the XML element returned has only attributes and no child.

Here is the SOAP data sent by the server :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <context xmlns="urn:zimbra">
      <change token="4"/>
    </context>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
      <CreateAppointmentResponse calItemId="259" rev="4" ms="4" invId="259-258" apptId="259" xmlns="urn:zimbraMail"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is my C# source code where I try to get the XML element named   CreateAppointmentResponse and its attributes :

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("contextValue")]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("urn:zimbraMail/CreateAppointmentRequest", ResponseElementName = "CreateAppointmentResponse", RequestNamespace = "urn:zimbraMail", ResponseNamespace = "urn:zimbraMail", ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped, Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CreateAppointmentResponse")]
public CreateAppointmentResponse CreateAppointmentRequest(Msg m) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("CreateAppointmentRequest", new object[] { m });
    return ((CreateAppointmentResponse)results[0]);
}
```

The results variable of type object[]  contains an array of one NULL element.

I think I need to change this line but I couldn't find what to do :

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CreateAppointmentResponse")]
```

What do you guys think ?

Regards

Victor